# Actionscript Class Communication

Tags: flash, class, actionscript

I'm new to ActionScript, and I have a question.

I am within a class, "Enemy". This class has a function "collision". How can I communicate with the amount of lives a player has left from within this class? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionScript Class Number Communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728927/actionscript-class-number-communication)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
public class Game extends MovieClip {
   public var enemy:Enemy; //enemy can be a timeline instance
   public var player:Player //can also be a timeline instance
   public function Game() {
        super();
        //for this to work enemy must exist on frame one of the Game MC
        //and stay around for the rest of the MC's lifespan
        enemy.addEventListener(EnemyEvent.COLLISION, onEnemyCollision);
   }
   protected function onEnemyCollision(e:EnemyEvent):void {
      e.player.lives--;
   }
}

//the enemy!!!
public class Enemy extends Sprite {
   //I actually don't understand why this is a function on enemy.
   //I wouldn't have designed it this way.
   //What is calling it?
   public function collision(withPlayer:Player):void {
      dispatchEvent(new EnemyEvent(EnemyEvent.COLLISION, withPlayer));
   }
}

//the player
public class Player extends Sprite {
   public var lives:int=10;
}

//the enemy event
public class EnemyEvent extends Event {
   public static const COLLISION:String = 'Big badda boom.';//Fifth Element reference
   public var player:Player;
   public function EnemyEvent(type:String, player:Player) {
       super(type, true, true);
       this.player = player;
   }
   public function clone():Event {
      new EnemyEvent(type, player);
   }
}
```

If you don't want to have the player and enemy on frame one, check out this post for more about how this stuff works in depth: http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html . Or you can write the code to add them in manually, but that's too much like work.

Comment: `+1` although I *really* dislike heavily event-driven games.

Comment: In this case, the OP probably doesn't need events. I suspect that the "thing" that is calling collision also knows about player, but that wasn't how the question was worded.