# ActionScript Class Number Communication

Tags: oop, class, actionscript

I'm a little new to AS3, but I have a question.

I have a variable called "lives". It is a Number. I also have a class. It is called "Enemy". Within the "Enemy" class, there is a function called "collision_detection". How can I change the value of "lives" from "collision_detection"? Thank you!

EDIT:

I have an Enemy class. I need to communicate from within the class to let the main program know that a collision occurred. How can I send this message to the main program?

EDIT II:

Here is the collision function :

```
public class Enemy extends MovieClip {

    private var hoster : MovieClip; 
    private var life: Number; 

    public function temp_bad_thing(host : MovieClip , lives : Number) {

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , check_collision); 

        hoster = host; 
        life = lives; 

        this.y = 0; 
        this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(551));


    }

    private function check_collision (evt:Event) : void{

    if(this.hitTestObject(hoster) == true){

        trace('COLLISION'); 

        parent.removeChild(this); 

        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , check_collision); 

        }

    }

}
```

Now how can I get this class to change the value of a variable in my main flash file?

Comment: The description is nice, but code would be more helpful. =)

Comment: The problem with written descriptions is that oftentimes the code may not be doing what you think it's doing (this tends to be A LOT when it's not acting correctly in the first place). Without knowing the context of what you have (code) it's going to be hard for anyone to answer this question.

Comment: Okay, here is some code... please stick around for a moment!

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is declared in the same `package` and not in another `class` you should be able to assign to it without doing anything special.

If it's in another class then declare the `lives` variable as `static public var lives: Number`. This way you can assign to the variable using `otherClass.lives`. Only one copy of `static` variable will exist regardless of how many objects you make.

Comment: It's not in a class. It's just in the main file. You know, with the timeline and whatnot?